# Other way to achive GWTP placeManager than Constructor's @Inject annotation

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, gwtp, gwt-platform

I use GWTP and restyGWT. I would like to use placeManager in restyGWT DispatcherCallback, when my rest server will answer with `401 unauthorised` I would like to redirect application to login page, that User could apply credentials and retried his request.

To do this I have to somehow get instance of PlaceManager (from gwtp framework). I cannot use `@Inject` annotation, cause I have manuall call to constructor as follow:

```
public class ForbiddenDispatcherFilter implements DispatcherFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
        builder.setCallback(new ForbiddenDispatcherCallback(method));
        return true;
    }
}


public class ForbiddenDispatcherCallback implements RequestCallback {
    protected RequestCallback requestCallback;

    public ForbiddenDispatcherCallback(Method method) {
        this.requestCallback = method.builder.getCallback();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.SC_FORBIDDEN || response.getStatusCode() == Response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        // make a hard redirect to login page
        // TODO change redirect to GWTP native
        Window.Location.assign("#login");
        // PlaceRequest placeRequest = new
        // PlaceRequest.Builder(placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest()).nameToken(Routing.Url.login).build();
        // placeManager.revealPlace(placeRequest);
    } else {
        requestCallback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
    }

}


public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    public RestyDispatcher() {
    addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter());
    addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public Request send(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) throws RequestException {
    return super.send(method, builder);
    }
}
```

Please help.

---

Edit

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();

    install(new DefaultModule.Builder()//
        .defaultPlace(Routing.HOME.url)//
        .errorPlace(Routing.ERROR.url)//
        .unauthorizedPlace(Routing.LOGIN.url)//
        .tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class).build());
    install(new AppModule());
    // install(new
    // GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(AssistedInjectionFactory.class));

    bind(CurrentUser.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(IsAdminGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(UserLoginGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);

    // Google Analytics
    // bindConstant().annotatedWith(GaAccount.class).to("UA-8319339-6");

    // Load and inject CSS resources
    bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();

    }

}
```

and:

```
public class RestyGwtConfig {

    static {

    // GWT.log("--> RestyGwtConfig -> setDispatcher");
    Defaults.setDispatcher(new RestyDispatcher());

    // GWT.log("--> RestyGwtConfig -> setServiceRoot");
    Defaults.setServiceRoot(new Resource(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve(ServiceRouting.SERVICE_ROOT).getUri());
    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setUserName("ronan");
    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setPassword("password");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How and where do you create your `ForbiddenDispatcherFilter` ?

You could use guice's [AssistedInjection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) to inject the `PlaceManager` into your `ForbiddenDispatcherCallback`.

```
public class ForbiddenDispatcherCallback implements RequestCallback {
    protected RequestCallback requestCallback;
    protected PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    public ForbiddenDispatcherCallback(PlaceManager placeManager, @Assisted Method method) {
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
        this.requestCallback = method.builder.getCallback();
    }
}
```

You need to define an factory interface:

```
public interface AssistedInjectionFactory {
    ForbiddenDispatcherCallback createForbiddenCallback(Method method);
}
```

In the `configure` method of your `ClientModule` you need to call:

```
install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(AssistedInjectionFactory.class));
```

Then you can instantiate your class this way:

```
public class ForbiddenDispatcherFilter implements DispatcherFilter {
    AssistedInjectionFactory factory;

    @Inject
    public ForbiddenDispatcherFilter(AssistedInjectionFactory factory) 
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
        builder.setCallback(factory.AssistedInjectionFactory(method)) 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course this requires that you also inject the `ForbiddenDispatcherFilter`.

### Edit:

You could try to pass the `RestyDispatcher` to the constructor of your `RestyGWTConfig`:

```
public class RestyGwtConfig {

    @Inject
    public RestyGwtConfig(RestyDispatcher dispatcher) {
        Defaults.setDispatcher(dispatcher);
    }

    static {
    // GWT.log("--> RestyGwtConfig -> setServiceRoot");
    Defaults.setServiceRoot(new Resource(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve(ServiceRouting.SERVICE_ROOT).getUri());
    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setUserName("ronan");
    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setPassword("password");
    }
}
```

The `RestyDispatcher` looks like this:

```
public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    @Inject
    public RestyDispatcher(ForbiddenDispatcherFilter filter) {
      addFilter(filter);
      addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public Request send(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) throws RequestException {
      return super.send(method, builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exacly I shoud do to inject `ForbiddenDispatcherFilter`? Do I have to create another `AssistedInjectionFactory` for this for ForbiddenDispatcherFilter?

Comment: It depends. How and where exactly do you currently instantiate the `ForbiddenDispatcherFilter` ?

Comment: I use it ony in RestyDispatcher class only. I use it in constructor with `addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter())`. I've updated post with `RestyDispatcher` class

Comment: Where do you create the `RestyDispatcheher`? In the Bootstrapper ?
You can inject the `ForbiddenDispatchFilter` into the `RestyDispatcher`

Comment: I Use it in `RestyGwtConfig` class, which is used in: `ClientModule` class. I will post both code in a sec.

Comment: Now I have an error in `RerstyDispatcher` which says: `The constructor ForbiddenDispatcherFilter() is undefined` I have to somehow Inject `ForbiddenDispatcherFIlter` with `AssistedInjectionFactory` instance to RestyDispatcher constructor instead this line: `addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter());`. How to do this?

Please post code of class `RestyDispatcher`.

Comment: Great. Works. Thanks.