# Resty-GWT custom callback on async start and end

Tags: rest, gwt, callback, resty-gwt

I use resty gwt for all server communication. I would like some indicator that would show the operation is in progress.

I consider 2 aproaches:

- progressbar, which will show in progress percentage;
- animation, that will be showed while operation is in progress, but without any percantage.

I've assumed that I need to add custom filter with callback. 
I would like to fire events like: `RestyGwtComunicationStart` and `RestyGwtComunicationEnd`, or callback to fire `onComunicationStarted` and 
`onComunicationEnded`. I would like to have this declared in one place, RestyGWT Dispatcher configuration. Also if there was an error I would like to fetch the error.

But I don't know where to start. There is no word about it in documentations.

Can I ask You for help? How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Do you need progress info (10%, 20% etc) or do you need only to know that a particular request has been sent ?

Comment: Both would be great :D, but for now simplest solution would be enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not get adequate answer, So I developed my own solution.

At first I've added Resty configuration `RestyGwtConfig` to my Module configuration

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();
        install(new DefaultModule.Builder()
        .defaultPlace(Routing.HOME.url)
        .errorPlace(Routing.ERROR.url)
        .unauthorizedPlace(Routing.LOGIN.url)
        .tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class).build());
        install(new AppModule());
        install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(AssistedInjectionFactory.class));
        bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

then I've set Custom distpatcher for all my comunication requests of resty gwt.

```
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Defaults;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Resource;
import pl.korbeldaniel.cms.shared.ServiceRouting;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class RestyGwtConfig {
    @Inject
    public RestyGwtConfig(RestyDispatcher dispatcher) {
        Defaults.setDispatcher(dispatcher);
    }
}
```

Then I've added custom filter (`ProgressIndicatorFilter`) to handle communication's **start** and **end callbacks**:

```
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Method;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.dispatcher.DefaultFilterawareDispatcher;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.Request;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestException;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {
    @Inject
    public RestyDispatcher(ProgressIndicatorFilter progressIndicatorFilter) {
        addFilter(progressIndicatorFilter);
    }
}
```

in filter class method overriden `filter` I've added an event trigger (`eventBus.fireEvent(new IndicatorEvent("Rest-Gwt Comunication started"));`) and registered callback, here is whole code:

```
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Method;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.dispatcher.DispatcherFilter;
import pl.korbeldaniel.cms.client.template.progressIndicator.IndicatorEvent;
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;

class ProgressIndicatorFilter implements DispatcherFilter {
    private AssistedInjectionFactory factory;
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public ProgressIndicatorFilter(AssistedInjectionFactory factory, EventBus eventBus) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
        builder.setCallback(factory.createProgressIndicatorCallback(method));
        eventBus.fireEvent(new IndicatorEvent("Resty-Gwt Comunication started"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Registering a callback couldn't be done straight forward, like

`new ProgressIndicatorDispatcherCallback()`

cause I use dependency injection. So I've created a factory to assist injection as follow:

```
public interface AssistedInjectionFactory {
    ProgressIndicatorDispatcherCallback createProgressIndicatorCallback(Method method);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770706/other-way-to-achive-gwtp-placemanager-than-constructors-inject-annotation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349799/restygwt-custom-dispatcher-doesnt-call-registered-filters) You can find more Assisted Injection info.

Here is the callback code:

```
class ProgressIndicatorDispatcherCallback implements RequestCallback {
    private RequestCallback requestCallback;
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public ProgressIndicatorDispatcherCallback(@Assisted Method method, EventBus eventBus) {
        this.requestCallback = method.builder.getCallback();
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        endComunicationFireIvent();
        requestCallback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        endComunicationFireIvent();
        requestCallback.onError(request, exception);
    }
    private void endComunicationFireIvent() {
        eventBus.fireEvent(new IndicatorEvent("Rest-Gwt Comunication ended"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to know that a request has been sent it is up to you in your GWT app to treat that. You can send an event when you trigger your request. You have multiple way of doing this.

Have a look at Request Dispatcher inside the doc https://resty-gwt.github.io/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html

Then if you want to get progress info, as HTTP calls are synchronous. So there is no way to do this easily.

The way I have been doing it is the following:

1) Create a first call to initiate a processing on the backend with a POST, this will return the ID of your processing

2) Then do a GET on your processing ID that will return the progress. Once the progress is 100% it will return the ID of the result

3) GET the result with the result ID

(You can mix 2 and 3 together eventually and return result when progress is 100% in the same DTO)

Another option is to replace 2) by pushing info from backend to front end (html5 websocket)

Comment: I know how http works. I need solution that will work with resty-GWT api. There is special filter mechanism, where I need to fire events.

Comment: btw this pull request comes from an old teammate :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone already did it as a pull-request to resty. Guess you can give it a try:

https://github.com/resty-gwt/resty-gwt/pull/151

Comment: well what we did is created a Provider for the client-side services, and the provider wraps all the calls and AsyncCallbacks. Perhaps there's just no simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "Dispatcher/Callback filters" feature does not described in the official documentation. But I can suggest next solution (this code should be placed in EntryPoint implementation of your module):

```java
public void onModuleLoad() {
    //...

    //used to show busy indicator before send HTTP request        
    DispatcherFilter busyIndicatorDispatcherFilter = new DispatcherFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
            BusyIndicator.show();
            return true;
        }
    };
    //used to show busy indicator after HTTP response recieved
    CallbackFilter busyIndicatorCallbackFilter = new CallbackFilter() {
        @Override
        public RequestCallback filter(Method method, Response response, RequestCallback callback) {
            BusyIndicator.hide();
            return callback;
        }
    };
    //registering FilterawareDispatcher (and busy indicator filters) as default Dispatcher
    Defaults.setDispatcher(new DefaultFilterawareDispatcher(
            busyIndicatorDispatcherFilter,
            new DefaultDispatcherFilter(new DefaultCallbackFactory(busyIndicatorCallbackFilter))));

    //...
}
```

Comment: Your's answer was the best of all.